# Selecting popup without title and clicking button inside it with geb

Tags: selenium, testing, geb

I have a popup without title and I want to detect the window using any other criteria (for example a div that wraps the whole popup) and click a button inside it.

I've tried the following:

```
        when:
            withWindow({ $("div", class:"main.msgAlert" )}) {

                $('#close').click()

        }
            then: true
```

But I always get a `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException` at te #close action. 
Am I failing at detecting the window or is the error related to the button?

Comment: Can you share the source code please?

Comment: The code only clicks a button that prompts a popup using  $('#pop').click(), nothing besides that.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot and a bit of the html?